# Send local broadcast message in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: notifications, windows-phone-8.1

As in Android we have Broadcast and in iOS we have NSNotifiactionCenter to send background messages and notifications...

There is something equivalent in Windows Phone 8.1??
I'm looking for documentation about this but I cannot find anything.

Thanks a lot!!
Jorge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no broadcast in WP 8.1, but for this i'm using implementation from Caliburn framework.

https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/blob/master/src/Caliburn.Micro/EventAggregator.cs

edit:

or you can implement your own broadcast - I used this in one of my projects

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

/* Created by Jan Kobersky - 8/28/2015 6:46:06 PM */
namespace EveryDay.Code.Core
{
    public class EventDispatcher
    {
        private static EventDispatcher _data;
        public static EventDispatcher Dispatcher => _data ?? (_data = new EventDispatcher());

        private readonly List<object> _subscribers = new List<object>();

        private EventDispatcher()
        {

        }

        public void Subscribe(object subscriber)
        {
            if (!_subscribers.Contains(subscriber))
            {
                _subscribers.Add(subscriber);
            }
        }

        public void Unsubscribe(object subscriber)
        {
            if (_subscribers.Contains(subscriber))
            {
                _subscribers.Remove(subscriber);
            }
        }

        public void Dispatch<T>(T message) where T : class
        {
            foreach (var subscriber in _subscribers)
            {
                (subscriber as IHandle<T>)?.Handle(message);
            }
        }
    }

    public interface IHandle<T> where T : class
    {
        void Handle(T message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking about implement my own broadcast as you said, but I supposed that WP8.1 would have something to dispatch messages in background... and because of that I've posted that question. I was wrong.